# I have a list stored as string in IronPython, Spotfire. How do I retrieve it back in the original list format?

Tags: scripting, ironpython, spotfire

A list is stored in the form of string in Document.Properties in Spotfire using IronPython script since Document.Properties doesn't directly support list type.

## Saving into Document property to use it in other scripts

mylist = ['13','24','57']
print mylist

> > > ['13','24','57']

Document.Properties["mylist"] = str(mylist)

## Retrieving the list stored in the form of string

This is where I need help. I need to access each element in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `",".join(str(x) for x in mylist)` to convert a list to string.

```
mylist = ['13','24','57']
print(",".join(str(x) for x in mylist))
>>>>13,24,57
```

Also Document Properties can accept a list. The document property simply needs to be a multi-select rather than a string.

Comment: Thank you. Using property control I was able to create a stringList type in document property.

Comment: Please approve the answer! Thank you